Flutter bottom navigation bar items overflowing individually
My flutter bottomNavigationBar items are overflowing from bottom. The error message is shown for every item individually. Although the items are aligned perfectly. I want to keep the same styling of bottom navigation and its items with the issue solved.
Another exception was thrown: A RenderFlex overflowed by 24 pixels on the bottom.
Another exception was thrown: A RenderFlex overflowed by 24 pixels on the bottom.
Another exception was thrown: A RenderFlex overflowed by 47 pixels on the bottom.
Another exception was thrown: A RenderFlex overflowed by 24 pixels on the bottom.
Another exception was thrown: A RenderFlex overflowed by 24 pixels on the bottom. 

The relevant error-causing widget was:
  BottomNavigationBar
  BottomNavigationBar:file:///Users/macbook/Desktop/frontend/lib/widgets/BottomNavigation.dart:142:22
On => child: BottomNavigationBar(


Screenshot

here is my code
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    checkTokenAvailability(); 

    return Scaffold(
      extendBody: true,
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: IndexedStack(
        index: _selectedIndex,
        children: _widgetOptions,
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 15.0, left: 6, right: 6),
        child: Container(
          height: 85, // Reduced height
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
            border: Border.all(
              color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 194, 187, 187),
              width: 2.0,
            ),
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
          child: ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
            child: BottomNavigationBar(
            
              items: _buildBottomNavBarItems(),
              currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
              onTap: _onItemTapped,
              selectedLabelStyle: const TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black,
                fontFamily: 'Poppins',
              ),
              unselectedLabelStyle: const TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black,
                fontFamily: 'Poppins',
              ),
              selectedIconTheme: const IconThemeData(size: 29),
              selectedFontSize: 14,
              unselectedFontSize: 12,
              type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
              selectedItemColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0),
              unselectedItemColor: Color.fromARGB(187, 0, 0, 0),
              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
              elevation: 5,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  // Helper function to build BottomNavigationBarItems
  List<BottomNavigationBarItem> _buildBottomNavBarItems() {
    List<BottomNavigationBarItem> items = [
      const BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
          child: Icon(Icons.login),
        ),
        label: 'Login',
      ),
      const BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
          child: Icon(Icons.local_car_wash,),
        ),
        label: 'Carwash',
      ),
      
    BottomNavigationBarItem(
  icon: Container(
    height: 55.0,
    width: 50.0,
    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
      shape: BoxShape.circle,
      color: Color.fromARGB(218, 244, 67, 54),
    ),
    child: const Icon(
      Icons.location_on,
      size: 31.0,
      color: Colors.white,
    ),
  ),
  label: '', // Ensure label is empty to avoid unnecessary space
),

      const BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
          child: Icon(Icons.home),
        ),
        label: 'For You',
      ),
      const BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
          child: Icon(Icons.account_circle),
        ),
        label: 'Profile',
      ),
    ];


    return items;
  }
}

PS: I don't want to add SafeArea widget. It just cuts the app from bottom and top (I know to do the top:false, bottom:false)
If there is any solution around or I am missing something that will be very helpful to guide me.
My flutter bottom navigation items overflows from bottom. Although my items are aligned perfectly within the navigation bar. I want to fix this issue.

You can increase the 2px height on height: 85+2 , usually you don't need to provide height

@Md.YeasinSheikh yess.. but i have to add 22 pixels not 2. And adding 22 pixels just make the bottom navigation height too large.  The problem was whole of the child Container of the bottomNavigationBar. I removed it and changed my bottom navigation design a little because I had a change in design requirement for bottom navigation. Now all good. Thanks for the reply

The problem was the child container of the BottomNavigationBar. I removed it, here is the code:
return Scaffold(
  extendBody: true,
  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  body: IndexedStack(
    index: _selectedIndex,
    children: _widgetOptions,
  ),
  bottomNavigationBar: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0, right: 8.0,),
    child: ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(30), topRight: Radius.circular(30)),
      child: SizedBox(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.122, 
        child: BottomNavigationBar(
          items: _buildBottomNavBarItems(),
          currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
          onTap: _onItemTapped,
          selectedLabelStyle: const TextStyle(
            color: Colors.black,
            fontFamily: 'Poppins',
          ),
          unselectedLabelStyle: const TextStyle(
            color: Colors.black,
            fontFamily: 'Poppins',
          ),
          selectedFontSize: 13,
          type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
          selectedIconTheme: const IconThemeData(size: 29),
          selectedItemColor: Colors.black,
          unselectedItemColor: const Color.fromARGB(167, 0, 0, 0),
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          elevation: 5,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);

}
List<BottomNavigationBarItem> _buildBottomNavBarItems() {
    return [
      const BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.login),
        label: 'Login',
      ),
      const BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.local_car_wash),
        label: 'Carwash',
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Container(
          margin: _selectedIndex == 2 ? const EdgeInsets.only(top: 0) : const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8),
          height: 50.0,
          width: 50.0,
          decoration:  BoxDecoration(
            shape: BoxShape.circle,
            color: _selectedIndex == 2 ? Color.fromARGB(246, 244, 67, 54) : Color.fromARGB(218, 244, 67, 54),
          ),
          child: Icon(
            Icons.location_on,
            size: _selectedIndex == 2 ? 32 : 32,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
        label: '',
      ),
      const BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.home),
        label: 'For You',
      ),
      const BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle),
        label: 'Profile',
      ),
    ];
  }


